# How to store 300gb+ data into mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I have one table in mysql db and its around 300+ gb in size. Querying it has become a performance overhead now.

I am looking for insights on storing and querying such size of data in a fast manner.

Any advice would be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the table normalized? If not, one of the first steps you could look at is seeing if you could break up the one large table into several, normalized tables until it reaches BCNF form.

The benefits of normalizing the table would be that you would be querying much smaller tables which should help increase your speed, as you don't have to go through as many unnecessary columns.

There's a lot of write-ups on normalization, so I won't bother going over it in much detail.

http://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/definition/normalization

http://searchoracle.techtarget.com/answer/What-is-the-Boyce-Codd-normal-form

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: As I am not a DB expert, I would like to share some info so that I can get more insights from you. Currently, I have 800 attributes and some huge number of rows in a table. One column has 14K unique values..Will normalization help in such a case or I should think about changing the table structure.

Comment: It truly depends on the data. The whole point of Normalization summed up, is that you are creating new tables (With Primary/Foreign keys referencing each-other as needed) that only contain the data that is absolutely necessary. This is usually done by determining your table dependencies (partial dependencies, transitive dependencies, etc) and putting them into their own tables. 

As I don't know your business requirements or data, I can't say for sure what these dependencies would be. Though, with a single table of that size, it seems very unlikely that it has been created correctly.